# Use of + sign in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I came across the (+) sign in one of the queries and after some research I understood that it means left outer join. However, I am not able to understand this query. Please rewrite this query without (+) sign.

```
 select e.masterid from streamed_events e, masters_encode m where 
 e.masterid = m.id (+) and 
 COMPANY_ID_R = m.company_id(+) and 
 m.id is NULL and m.company_id is  NULL
```

Thanks for all your help....

Comment: This is the syntax for outer joins in Oracle. The join syntax changed since Oracle 9i.

Comment: Oracle's particular join syntax didn't change. In addition to the (+) syntax, Oracle now supports the ansi join syntax.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger Point Noted.

Answer (score 2):

The plus sign denotes optional table in JOIN

```
select e.masterid 
from streamed_events e
LEFT OUTER JOIN  masters_encode m 
 ON e.masterid = m.id  and  COMPANY_ID_R = m.company_id
WHERE m.id is NULL and m.company_id is  NULL
```

[**Documentation**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#SQLRF52336)

Comment: What is `COMPANY_ID_R` ? Why did you decide to make it a part of the join?

Comment: Since it is not aliased , I am assuming its not present in masters_encode table and so there is no problem of " ambigous column "

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.masterid
from streamed_events e
left outer join masters_encode m on e.masterid = m.id and COMPANY_ID_R = m.company_id
where m.id is NULL and m.company_id is  NULL
```

Although there is something odd about that query.  It appears it is looking for rows in `streamed_events` that don't have a corresponding row in `masters_encode`, since those are the rows that will have a null `m.id` and `m.company_id`.  The strange part is it is using a variable `COMPANY_ID_R` to match on `m.company_id` but then only selecting it if null.

Maybe if you could explain what it is trying to do I could give a better answer.

Comment: Trying to select records that exist in streamed_events, but don't exist in the masters_encode is my guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.masterid 
from streamed_events e 
left outer join masters_encode  on e.masterid= m.id 
left outer join COMPANY on  COMPANY_ID_R =m.company_id 
where m.id is NULL and m.company_id is  NULL
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  There is no table called `company` in the original query.